# Two definitions of exactness

Tags: commutative-algebra

Given a functor $F:A\to B$ of abelian categories we may say that $F$ is left exact if it maps exact sequences to left exact sequences, and similarily for right. For arbitrary categories, we may say that $F$ is left exact if it preserves finite limits (supposedly, this was introduced in SGAIV, but I don't have it). The question is thus: are these definitions equivalent in an abelian category? That this latter definition implies the first is clear to me, but the other gives me more trouble.

Thanks,

Eivind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $F$ is exact in the first sense if it maps *left* exact sequences to left exact sequences (this is an easy exercise). So $F$ is exact in the first sense iff it preserves kernels. But an additive functor that preserves kernels preserves all finite limits (because any finite limit can be built from a product of direct products and equalizers, and finite direct products are always preserved by an additive functor).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suspected it would have something to do with building the limit from products and equalizers. That fact will probably prove a good exercise :)